# (Python) How can I find out if there are other equal values of opposite sign?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python similar to the one in the picture and I was wondering how can I get to the same output. So if I have a certain value and there exists another value of opposite sign in that row (-360 and 360 for example) which has the same date (same month more exactly), then I have to create a new variable that outputs '+/- same month'. Likewise if the values are from different months, then '+/- different month". If there is no opposite value then I just have to print whether the value is positive or negative. I have tried to do this with 2 for loops but I have failed miserably and I am out of ideas.

[Example of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj6uz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta rush, I will add a description in the evening

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

test_data = [
                {'Title': "Account1", 'Amount': 100, 'Date': '2019-11-13'},
                {'Title': "Account1", 'Amount': -100, 'Date': '2019-11-17'},
                {'Title': "Account2", 'Amount': 200, 'Date': '2019-11-14'},
                {'Title': "Account2", 'Amount': -200, 'Date': '2019-12-14'},
                {'Title': "Account3", 'Amount': 300, 'Date': '2020-01-01'}
            ]

test_data = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
test_data['Month'] = test_data['Date'].apply(lambda x: x[:-3])

positiv_amount = test_data[test_data['Amount'] > 0]
negative_amout = test_data[test_data['Amount'] < 0]

compare = pd.merge(how='left',
         left= positiv_amount, 
         right=negative_amout, 
         left_on='Title', right_on='Title',suffixes=['_positive', '_negative'])




conditions = [
    (compare['Amount_negative'].isnull()),
    (compare['Month_positive'] == compare['Month_negative']),
    (compare['Month_positive'] != compare['Month_negative'])]

choices = ['', 'Same Month', 'Different Month']

compare['output'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

print(compare)`
```

```
      Title  Amount_positive Date_positive Month_positive  Amount_negative    Date_negative Month_negative      output
0  Account1              100    2019-11-13        2019-11           -100.0     2019-11-17        2019-11  Same Month  
1  Account2              200    2019-11-14        2019-11           -200.0     2019-12-14        2019-12  Different Month  
2  Account3              300    2020-01-01        2020-01            NaN            NaN            NaN
```